# OverlayContainer vs. FullscreenOverlayContainer

Tags: angular-material2

I had some issues in full-screen mode using `OverlayContainer`.

The solution is to use [FullscreenOverlayContainer](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#full-screen-overlays) (which also works in full-screen mode)

> The FullscreenOverlayContainer is an alternative to OverlayContainer that supports correct displaying of overlay elements in fullscreen mode.

Now, I wonder why `OverlayContainer` exists at all:

- Are there any drawbacks in using `FullscreenOverlayContainer`?
- In which situations would we use `OverlayContainer` instead of `FullscreenOverlayContainer`?

Comment: related [angular-components issue 16651](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16651)

Comment: related https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [comment in #19434](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19434#issuecomment-634976066)

> original reasoning was that handling full-screen mode was extra code that not everyone necessarily needed

So when you want to save some extra bytes and really don't need full-scrren you may use `OverlayContainer`.
My take on this is to always use `FullscreenOverlayContainer`.